# Incomplete content fetch at XMLHTTPRequest or Jquery GET on a dynamic webpage (Ajax loaded)

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest

Using XMLHTTPRequest as below

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "https://swym.3ds.com/", false);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function(data) {
  if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status==200) {
        var fakePage = document.createElement("html");
        fakePage.innerHTML = data;
        console.log(fakePage.innerHTML);
        // find the desired element within the new page element
        statone = $(fakePage).find('#widgetPanel-7qrSN8CAwqKk0DP2_GQK').text();
        console.log(statone);
    }
}
xhr.send();
```

Using Jquery GET Method:

```
$.get("https://swym.3ds.com/", function(data) { 
        // load response text into a new page element
        var fakePage = document.createElement("html");
        fakePage.innerHTML = data;

        // find the desired element within the new page element
        statone = $(fakePage).find('#widgetPanel-7qrSN8CAwqKk0DP2_GQK').text();
        console.log(statone);
    }
);
```

Since the page (https://swym.3ds.com/) loads by Ajax action , even before the page loading completes, ready state and status of page loading gets 4 and 200. i.e. the extracted data has incomplete information of webcontent or DOM.

Query: how to introduce a delay of 5 seconds for the GET method to fetch the completet webpage content or DOM information ?

Comment: Are you asking how to do a setTimeout()?

Comment: I'm bit familiar with setTimeout(), issue is that get or XMLHttpRequest does their job as soon as the page loading state is complete, but since the page is loaded with Ajax or Javascript dynamicaly with respect to user profile, it takes time to load the DOM elements. What i got from this piece of code is just a page loading ajax DOM, what i need is post content DOM loaded by AJAX or Javascript.